# Can you do chi-square test of independence on quantized continuous random variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, random-variable

Say I have a sample with m observations, each observation has two features  X and Y which are continuous random variables. I'm interested in knowing if you can bin X and Y each into N quantiles, create a contingency table and do chi-suqare test using # of observations to test their independence? What are the caveats of doing that?
[Edit] removed some unrelated part

Comment: You can bin continuous variables into discrete variables and perform a standard chi-squared test of independence if the bins are not dependent on the data (using quantiles to define bins would be data-dependent; that would affect the distribution). However, it's not advisable to discretize your data; you can lose a lot of information; chi-squared tests are very low-powered against typical alternatives and may exhibit bias against some alternatives.

Comment: The caveats I provided for the one-way chi-squared test (at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/919) apply, *mutatis mutandis,* to this two-way test.